# Retrieving facebook page JSON feed is not working

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I have tested it and write the direct URL on the URL bar:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/my_page_id/feed?access_token=my_token
```

But all it shows are blank JSON feed:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

How can I get the new feed?

Comment: Are you using extended access token or regular token ? Normally Access token are valid for a short time period only about 1 to 2 hours.

Comment: I have retrieve my token from Graph API Explorer.Is it extended or short ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have found it :)
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=page_id&format=json

You can found your page id by https://graph.facebook.com/page_name

Answer (score 1):

api check connection to your server . request should be send by curl. so direct url pasting would not be working.
upload files to server or make virtualhost then send request from sever .
[check Publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)
to know [about curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180029/facebook-api-what-is-curl-f)

Comment: Please explain little bit more.I have also tried it in  [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=430592810329491%2Ffeed)
`request should be send by curl` please explain it little more

Comment: check the link, while publising the data it should request from server by facebook app . Graph API explorer is also a facebook app and located on server .it is for api testing only.

Comment: So how can I achieve that? Please explain it with code in staright-forward way as I am new in facebook API :(

Comment: do you created any facebook app? if not [create](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) one

Comment: yes, I have created one. This is the app id `111396415692983`.

Comment: I have to create a JSON feed for this facebook App (facebook page).Can you give me a straight-forward way to achieve this? I am so dumb to get your hints as I am new here.