# What is cURL '-F' param doing in terms of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request

I'm trying to copy a cURL command in node.js. The command is this:

```
curl https://search.craftar.net/v1/search -F "token=xxx" -F "image=@someImage.jpg"
```

This is fine, but how does this translate to node.js? Using the request library:

```
request({
    url: 'https://search.craftar.net/v1/search',
    method: 'POST',
    form: {token: 'xxx', image: binaryBodyOfPrevRequest},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
}, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(body) // prints out: {"error": {"message": "Reference image is required", "code": "IMAGE_MISSING"}}
});
```

It seems that my token is being recognised but the image is not. Why is that?

I've looked at [Facebook API - What is " curl -F "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180029/facebook-api-what-is-curl-f), and I see that it is a form. But I don't know how to compare the idea of an HTML form vs multipart/form-data, or what a form maybe in terms of data sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually setting the Content-Type and using `form`, just use `formData` instead of `form` in your `request()` options. That will send a multipart/form-data request instead of an application/x-www-form-urlencoded request. The reason you need to use multipart/form-data is that is generally the request type used to transfer raw binary data.

Additionally, if your image is local (or if you can obtain the image via a stream of some other kind), you can pass a stream to the file instead of the literal contents. This can help with memory usage since you won't have to buffer the entire file first. For example:

```
formData: {
  token: 'foo',
  image: fs.createReadStream('/path/to/image.jpg')
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The exact use case is that I'm retrieving an image from CouchDB, that I then send on. So I have the file as binary data in 'body'. Are you saying it would be preferable NOT to do that and to pipe to a file instead? At which point I would be able to use the fs.createReadStream to retrieve the contents?

Comment: I believe some couchdb drivers support streaming attachments (e.g. [`cradle`](https://github.com/flatiron/cradle#streaming-2)). You could also just download that attachment directly by making an HTTP request for [/{db}/{docid}/{attachmentName}](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/document/attachments.html#get--db-docid-attname) and using the HTTP response stream for the `image` value.

Comment: Thanks again. "or if you can obtain the image via a stream of some other kind". I had already made a request to /{db}/{docid}/{attName}, and received the attachment by binary stream in the body of the response. Using "var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });", I was able to send the body directly back to CouchDB as an attachment with content-type of image/jpeg. However I wasn't able to send the same body to craftar as it required a form. How do I create a stream from the return body of a request?

Comment: For example: `image: request('http://example.org:1234/db/docid/attName')`